# Finding timedifference in vba

Tags: excel, vba

[image]i want to find the time difference in a range.  I tried my code below and it didnt return the time difference in seconds but it only generate a value of "0" from the first row to fourth row in column D.

```
   Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
   Dim LastRowOfB As Long, LastRowOfD As Long
   Dim ColumnBRngData As Range, ColumnDRngData As Range
   
   LastRowOfB = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
   LastRowOfD = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
   Set ColumnBRngData = ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B" & LastRowOfB)
   Set ColumnDRngData = ActiveSheet.Range("D4:D" & LastRowOfD)


   For i = 4 To LastRowOfB
       StartDate = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
       EndDate = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
       ColumnDRngData.Cells = (StartDate - EndDate) * 86400
   Next i
```

I want the time difference to be shown in range D4 and ownwards.

Comment: `ColumnDRngData = ...` is writing the result of `DateDiff` to the entire range, not a single cell.

Comment: Noted, i changed it to ColumnDRngData.Cells but it did generate the time diff value

Comment: No, that won't fix the problem. What is the setup of your sheet? Can you add a screenshot, or sample data and the expected result?

Comment: What do you mean by setup? Is it this-> The header of my data starts at row 3. Time is at col b, 2/10/2021  1:34:28 PM, ... and col d is where i want to paste the time diff

Comment: Please add a screenshot or sample data. Most likely you don't need two loops here.

Comment: I have done so!

Comment: I don't think you need VBA for this: in D4, put `=(D4-D5)*86400` and drag down. One day is equivalent to `1`. There are `86400` seconds in a day. So you can use simple subtraction and multiplication.

Comment: For my excel, i utilize vba  to import and generate a chart, thus i need to use vba to find timediff to plot the chart

Comment: it is in a range tho, thats why i use 2 loops to find the time diff

Comment: What is the expected result? It's unclear why you need 2 loops. Please include the expected result in your screenshot. Also make sure the formatting in column B allows one to see the seconds portion.

Comment: I cant format my cell to show the seconds

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: What then is the expected result in column D?

Comment: Perfect. So all you need to do now is to write that formula using VBA. No loop needed here.

Comment: How can i do so without a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

- You can use a formula to do this, no need to use `DateDiff` here. 1 day = 1 and there are 86400 seconds in a day.
- You can write the formula to the entire range without looping:

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim LastRowOfB As Long
    LastRowOfB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("D4:D" & LastRowOfB - 1).Formula = "=ROUND((B5-B4)*86400,0)"
End With
```